# show 1 or the other 2 options in select menu react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have this:

```
 <select
        onInput={(e) => onTyping(e.target.name, e.target.value)}
        name="site"
        id="site"
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        >
            <option value={myData.site}>{myData.site}</option>
            <option value="MAR">MARKHAM</option>
            <option value="OTT">OTTAWA</option>
        </select>
```

and basically what it is doing is just displaying the options for the locations, plus the one that is already selected. and what I need is to be is if `myData.site == mar` then display Ottawa, and Markham as the selected option, and vice versa for Ottawa. I tried to do a script inside the react `return`, but it doesn't like it. how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can conditionally render an element using ternary or logical operators inside of curly brackets

```
<option value={myData.site}>{myData.site}</option>
{myData.site == 'mar' && <option value="MAR">MARKHAM</option>}
{myData.site == 'ott' && <option value="OTT">OTTAWA</option>}
```